# How to build ffmpeg as a single application on Mac

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile ffmpeg on mac as a single executable static executable so it can be distributed. Here is my ./configure.

```
./configure \
    --pkg_config='pkg-config --static' \
    --enable-libopenh264 \
    --enable-version3 \
    --enable-libopus \
    --enable-libvpx \
    --enable-libvorbis \
    --enable-libaom \
    --enable-libdav1d \
    --enable-videotoolbox \
    --enable-hwaccel=h264_videotoolbox \
    --disable-gpl \
    --disable-w32threads \
    --enable-pthreads \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
  --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib" \
--prefix=~/FFmpeg/dist
```

Except it compiles it and still requires linked libraries. If I open it on another mac I get errors likeL

```
Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libxcb/lib/libxcb.1.dylib
```

And thoughts on what flags I am missing?

Comment: I've made some tests cross compiling for Windows. So in my case removing  `--disable-w32threads` and `--enable-pthreads` created a correct static build (with empty PATH it showed the version without errors). Though I also had to remove all the secondary libs (opus, vorbis, aom...). And of course I had cross- params (arch, target). So the basic idea is to remove 1 parameter at a time until reaching the correct behaviour. Or adding parameters to a correct minimal config, which in my case, apart from the cross compile necessary flags, was just specifying `--enable-static`.